# For loop IndexError

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am trying to run a for loop over a list of directories in order to extract specific values from some lines of a file within each directory. The structure of the directories is as follows:

```
# 'sourcedir' --> main directory
#   |
#   |___ alineamiento1 --> directory
#   |       |
#   |       |___ modelo1 --> sub-directory with the file
#   |       |___ modelo2
#   |
#   |___ alineamiento2
#           |
#           |___ modelo1
#           |___ modelo2
```

I have run the script over a main directory containing 15 directories and has worked out pretty well. However, when I try to run it over more directories (~100) the for loop crashes because of an IndexError.

This is the desired result:

```
>similarity_group_0202
-lnL m0 = -3491.164041
-lnL m1 = -3442.220417
Likelihood ratio = 97.887248, df = 26
El mejor modelo es m1. P-value = 1.09405887112e-10
```

And this is the IndexError output:

```
>similarity_group_0217
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LRTb.py", line 52, in <module>
    path_m1 = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), modelos[2])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Sometimes, this error occur after the 8th directory, other times after the 10th and so on. So, basically it is not an issue with the files within the directories.

Here is my script:

```
import os
import sys
import re
from scipy import stats

sourcedir = '<path/to/main/directory>'

sg=os.listdir(sourcedir)

sg[:] = [dirname for dirname in sg if dirname.startswith('s')]

n=len(sg)

grupos_m0=[]

grupos_m1=[]

for dirname in sg[0:n]:
    os.chdir(os.path.join(sourcedir, dirname))
    dir=os.getcwd()
    print(">" + dir.split(os.path.sep)[9])
    modelos = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
    path_m0 = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), modelos[1])
    path_m1 = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), modelos[2])
    os.chdir(path_m0)
    with open('out', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith('lnL'):
                Lm0 = float(line.split()[4])
                p0 = line.split()[3]
                p0 = re.findall('\d+', p0 )
                npm0 = int(p0[0])
        print("-lnL m0 = " + str(Lm0))
    os.chdir(path_m1)
    with open('out', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith('lnL'):
                Lm1 = float(line.split()[4])
                p1 = line.split()[3]
                p1 = re.findall('\d+', p1 )
                npm1 = int(p1[0])
        print("-lnL m1 = " + str(Lm1))
    LR = 2*(Lm1-(Lm0)) # Likelihood-ratio (2*delta(-lnL))
    df = npm1-npm0 
    print('Likelihood ratio = ' + str(LR) + ', ' + 'df = ' + str(df))
    p = stats.chi2.pdf(LR,df)
    if p < 0.05:
        print('El mejor modelo es m1. P-value = ' + str(p) + "\n")
        grupos_m1.append(dir.split(os.path.sep)[9])
    else:
        print('El mejor modelo es m0. P-value > 0.05)' + "\n")
        grupos_m0.append(dir.split(os.path.sep)[9])
print("Alineamientos donde el mejor modelo es m0: " + str(len(grupos_m0)) + "\n" + str(grupos_m0))

print("Alineamientos donde el mejor modelo es m1: " + str(len(grupos_m1)) + "\n" + str(grupos_m1))
```

Any help will be very much appreciated! 
Thanks!

Comment: what does `modelos` contain when it dies?

Comment: It contains three directories: `['.DS_Store', 'm0', 'm1']`. The ones of interest are m0 (`modelos[1]`) and m1 (`modelos[2]`).

Comment: Can you guarantee that '.DS_Store' is always present? My best guess from what you've provided is that `.DS_Store` doesn't always exist.

Comment: You were right! Apparently the '.DS_Store' wasn't always present. I did the following: `modelos[:] = [dirname for dirname in modelos if dirname.startswith('m')` and fix the indexes. That way it worked out! Thank you very much

Comment: By the way, is there a way to do `os.listdir()` without getting the hidden directories?

Comment: No, listdir() shows only what it reads in a semi-random order. You should use `filter(filter_func, os.listdir(...))` to filter desired file names you will work with later on.